# should I always start from the same start state in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In an episodic training of an RL agent should I always start from the same initial state or I can start from several valid initial states?

For example, in gym environment, should my env.reset() function always resets me to the same start state or it can start from different states at each training episode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a constraint from your environement: for most environments, you can not control the starting state and you have to learn from the experience you collect by getting into random states.

But in the event you can pick a starting state, it is making learning easier and faster: replaying many times the same state by testing different actions on just a few steps will reduce drastically the variance of your problem. By looking at smaller pieces of the problem at a time you learn faster.